# Reverse a javascript algorithm

Tags: javascript

Well guys, I'm learning javascript and I stumbled upon a kind of challenge code. I've already searched in google and I found some reverse codes but I couldn't understand or didn't work. The question is that I don't have any idea on how to reverse and put in a code, I'd like to see some reasonable snippet of code and understand it.

```
function checkString(strz) {
    var total = 0;
    var charlist   =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for ( var i = 0; i < strz.length; i++) {
            var countone =   strz.charAt (i); 
            var counttwo = (charlist.indexOf(countone)); 
            counttwo++;  
            total *= 17;  
            total += counttwo;  
    }
    if (  total == 248410397744610 ) {
            alert ("You're right!");
    }  
    else  {  
            alert  ("Sorry, but the string was incorrect." ) ;
    }
```

}

Comment: Just what in the world are you trying to do ? This scripts checks the input string to satisfy a particular property.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out a string that passes the test? What have you tried? What's your current thinking? We don't usually like "do all the work for me" questions.

Comment: Yea but I want to know what input satisfies such property.

Comment: I'd try to understand this piece by piece and ask a more specific question if you get stuck

Comment: In coding nothing but I'm trying some pen and paper math. No no, isn't homework or sort of it, I'm at vacations and "programming" it's a hobby.

Comment: I've understood the script I just don't know how to make a reverse code to find such string(s).

Comment: I've seen this one posed as an interview question. Give it some more thought, you'll figure it out.

Comment: I'm stuck on this for 2 days! Still nothing.

Comment: If you take that final number and compute the remainder after dividing by 17, you get the value that was added to `total` on the last iteration of the loop. You can then subtract that from the total and iterate. Keep track of the remainders on each iteration.

Comment: Jesus, thank you @Pointy ! I've got the string. How did you figure out? Can you explain me mathlly?

Comment: @Milbol well I just looked at the loop; the last thing that happens is the multiplication by 17 and then the addition. Thus, if we find the remainder after dividing by 17, that must be the value that was added in the last iteration. Subtracting that gives us the product before the addition (with remainder 0). Then you just repeat that.  (I was hoping the string would be something more interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

Edited response based on comment - this should display variables in the console log for each loop, then the final answer based on initial value provided.

```
console.log('final answer: ' + decipher('248410397744610'))
function decipher(code){
    var result = '';
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    for( var i=0; i < code.length; i++ ){
        var character = code.charAt(i);
        console.log(i + ' character: ' + character);
        var letter = alphabet[character];
        console.log(i + ' letter: ' + letter);
        var result = result.concat(letter);
        console.log(i + ' result: ' + result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The question basically is how to find the string that'll cause that function to consider it the "right" answer.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about my question, I'm not a native english speaker :X! Well, are you seeing the parameter in the checkString fuction? I have to put a correct value (when calling the function) which will correspond to the "248410397744610", and an alert "you're right" will pop up. Such correspondence depends on the value in that parameter because as you can see, there are some operations in the for loop. There're many strings to satisfy the input, I just don't know how to find them.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. I've edited my answer based on your comment. Is this what you're looking for? If not, I've added console logs inside the function so you can better see what's going on at each step, this might point you in the right direction to figure it out. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wasn't but as you said, it gave me a nice direction to create a script for such task. Look at Pointy responses, it's exactly what I had to do. 10Q you both!

Comment: Thanks! Glad we were able to help.